# pyHandle Object for win32pipe.PeekNamedPipe(pyHandle, bufsize)

Tags: python, winapi, named-pipes, pywin32

The win32pipe.PeekNamedPipe gets the arguments pyHandle(read handle) and a buf size . The pyHandles are returned by win32pipe.createPipe() which gives me a read and write handle to the pipes.

Now, assume I have got the handle/integer value of the read handle of this pipe to another process. I want to read the data on the handle using peekNamedPipe method by passing in a pyHandle.

I read elsewhere that functions tat accept pyHandles will also accept the int values, but in this case it does not , it gives me an error saying invalid handle when I try to pass the int.

Is there a way I can create a pyHandle Object with the integer that I have ?

Comment: Looks like the peekNamedPipe does accept the int value of the handle in the process which owns the handle. When I try to use the same int on the other process , it does not let me. Note that I had given 'none' as the security descriptor on the createPipe method. Is this expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about Python or pyHandles, but from your description it sounds as if a pyHandle is a thin wrapper around a Win32 HANDLE, in this case a HANDLE to a Pipe object.

HANDLEs in Windows are obtained from the operating system as the result of calling a variety of Win32 API functions, including CreatePipe. Most HANDLEs have process-affinity, and so can only be used by the process which acquired them.

In Win32, if you have a HANDLE to an object, and want to pass a reference to that object to another process, you have to explicitly call the API [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to ask the operating system to give you a handle which will work in the other process.

So if you can find a way to call `DuplicateHandle` using the numeric value from your original pyHandle, you should be able to transform it into a different handle value which can be used in the other process.